# How to add sales order table custom value to magento 2 report from a custom module

Tags: custom, magento2.2.4, custom-reports

I created a custom module to check the ad code (measure the marketing traffic) value from the url and add to the order. I added a column to the sales order table and save the ad value when user place the order.

Now I need to show this value in the sales report.

Can someone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: The value should need to be in sales_order_grid right? from sales_order table

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran- I was thinking to add the value to report.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran- Yes

Comment: @ Prathap Gunasekaran - I used left join to display the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Add a column in **sales_order_grid** table like you have in **sales_order**

Then add a **sales_order_grid.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                         
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
<column name="column_name_in_table">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Name Goes here</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>                                                    
</columns>                                                   
</listing>
```

then add **di.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
<arguments>
    <argument name="columns">
        <item name="customer_manager" xsi:type="string">sales_order.column_name_in_table</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>                                                     
</virtualType>                                                        
</config>
```

**column_name_in_table** is the name of column which you have in **sales_order** table and make you have same column in **sales_order_grid** table as well.

> NOTE : When you post data into sales_order table next time then it will also be added into sales_order_grid table as then xml will list the column in grid view and you can add filter and sortable option to it.

Run below commands after you made these changes

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps :)